# How to add place options for mapbox placeautocomplete

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android, placeautocompletefragment

```
PlaceOptions placeOptions=new PlaceOptions() {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Point proximity() {
            return null;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public String language() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int limit() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Integer historyCount() {
            return null;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public String bbox() {
            return null;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public String geocodingTypes() {
            return null;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public String country() {
            return null;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public List<String> injectedPlaces() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int viewMode() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int backgroundColor() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int toolbarColor() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int statusbarColor() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public String hint() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {

        }
    };

    Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder()
            .accessToken(R.string.token)
            .placeOptions(placeOptions)
            .build(this);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
```

I am trying to build custom PlaceAutocomplete, with custom language and country for Serbia. I am getting error about parcelable data, but I am unable to find a solution for a long time. Since I am working with MapBox, everything was easy and there was fully documentation, but for PlaceOptions there is nothing on their site.

```
Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class com.magma.magmataxi.LocationActivity$2
```

I was thinking that PlaceOptions.builder.build can help, but I am still not able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `PlaceOptions.builder()`

See https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/examples/global-location-search/.

Specifically https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/plugins/PlacesPluginActivity.java#L92-L101.

Also, be careful about posting your Mapbox token on the internet. It's now "exposed" and could be used by others. I'd rotate your token now so that it's secure.

Comment: Hello @langsmith. Thank you for the response, it helped me a lot. Although I was searching for this for a long time, somehow I missed it. Your answer is the correct one!

Comment: Yes, some Mapbox things can be hard to find and require some digging if you know where to look ;)

Glad it helped!